# mysql query to insert the value of a column with respect to another column in same table

Tags: mysql

Below is a sample table I've been working on,

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REVCA       ║ REDO ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  4 ║ 43453453345  ║  0   ║
║  2 ║ NULL         ║  0   ║
║  5 ║ NULL         ║  0   ║
║  7 ║ 5566533      ║  0   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I'm inserting **REVCA** value by the selection from another table.
I need to update **REDO** as **1** for each of the **NULL** values I get.

Below is the expected output

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REVCA       ║ REDO ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  4 ║ 43453453345  ║  0   ║
║  2 ║ NULL         ║  1   ║
║  5 ║ NULL         ║  1   ║
║  7 ║ 5566533      ║  0   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I'm using an **update** query presently

```
UPDATE \`REVCA \` SET  \` REDO\` = 1      
WHERE \`REVCA \`= 0;
```

I'm looking for an alternative as the size of database is very large.
I need it during the insertion itself.

I can use only plain sql for the purpose
Please help me accomplish the same.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
update table set redo = 1 where revca is null
```

While inserting:

```
insert into table(kid, revca, redo)
select @kid, @revca, case when @revca is null then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: @ Giorgi I'm using the same presently,but i need an alternative

Comment: The size of database I'm dealing is really large,so i cant run an update query as such. IS there any other

Comment: yes it works,but what if the case is **0** instead of null  i tried       CASE WHEN \`products_id\`= 0 then 1 else 0 end, but  doesnt work

Comment: `case when @revca is null or @revca  = '0' then 1 else 0 end`